# Can't display two items inline because one is within a 'for' loop and the other within an 'if' statement

Tags: html, css, liquid

I have to icons on a product page (Shopify's theme). I have the following code that displays the icons correctly, except I don't know how to display them inline. I tried wrapping everything in a div or a span with no luck. Here's the code:

```
<div class="barra-de-info">      
     {% for tag in product.tags %}
         {% if tag contains '_hecho _en _mexico' %}
            <div class"icono-hecho-en-mex" style="width: 80px;">{% include 'icon-hecho-en-mexico' %}</div> 
         {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
        {% if product.price >= 60000 %}
           <div class"icono-hecho-en-mex">{% include 'icon-free-shipping5' %}</div> 
        {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: Is `.icono-hecho-en-mex` an inline-block element ? If not do that. Besides that, what are the dimensions of the `div` in if statement?

Comment: It is an inline statement. There was a width of 80px in the if statetment. I corrected that to have no specific dimensions. Also made .barra-de-info an inline-block but it didn't help. I'm calling the images from an asset that imports an svg, using the img tag.